# Does IP Leasing Lock the IP For Duration of Lease?

Tags: networking, ip

I have been placed in charge of a hotel's wireless network, and I have some questions about IP leasing due the fact that this is a hotel I am dealing with, where new machines are constantly moving through...

If the lease is for 3 days and on the first day after the IP is allocated to the machine if the machine goes off the network, say out for the day, can another machine be allocated that IP while it is out of use if it is still within the time frame of the lease?

This is important to know because the guests only stay for a short period so if the lease is for a week and the average guests stays for two days, does that mean the IPs that are leased to their machines are locked down until the leases expire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is locked, because IP Lease happens on the server side. The server is instructed to give the same IP address to a connecting computer (with the same MAC address) for a pre-set period of time.

Comment: Thanks you. Good to know, validates my theory for the performance issues of the wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Another machine cannot be allocated, that's the whole reason to have a lease in the first place.  However, there's no reason not to set the lease to a short time, like an hour.  The client computer renews automatically and it's seamless to the user.  My ISP has it set somewhere in the range of a couple minutes.

Comment: Yeah already changed it prior to asking, but I acted from a theoretical impulse and wanted concrete validation for my employer.  Thanks.